# How to set up a charset different from utf-8 for a web site @github pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

'encoding:' setting at _config.yml doesn't seem to work, the server still sends Content-type: html, charset=utf-8 header which makes pages unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The [w3schools article on charset in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) would suggest that you can control this by adding `<meta charset="" />` to the layout for the page (`_layouts`).

If you're using a theme, you may have to clone the `_layouts` folder to your site repository, then edit it from there.